Wirtinger derivatives on a real plane
I came across the Wirtinger derivatives recently.
I am trying to apply the same logic to a real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$:
Let $f(r) = u(x, y)\vec{i} + v(x,y)\vec{j}$ be a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $r = x\vec{i} + y\vec{j}$ in an orthonormal basis $(\vec{i}, \vec{j})$.
Then:
$$\begin{cases} \mathrm dr = \mathrm dx\vec{i} + \mathrm dy\vec{j} \\ \mathrm dr^* = \mathrm dx\vec{i} - \mathrm dy\vec{j} \end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases} \mathrm dx\vec{i} = \frac{1}{2}(\mathrm dr + \mathrm dr^*) \\ \mathrm dy\vec{j} = \frac{1}{2}(\mathrm dr - \mathrm dr^*) \end{cases},$$
and considering the 2D geometric product $\vec{i}\vec{i} = \vec{j}\vec{j} = 1$: $$\begin{cases} \mathrm dx = \frac{\vec{i}}{2}(\mathrm dr + \mathrm dr^*) \\ \mathrm dy = \frac{\vec{j}}{2}(\mathrm dr - \mathrm dr^*) \end{cases}.$$
The differential of $f$:
$$\mathrm df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm dy = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j}\right)\mathrm dr + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vec{i} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\vec{j}\right)\mathrm dr^*.$$
Substituting $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\vec{i} + \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\vec{j}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\vec{i} + \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\vec{j}$:
$$\mathrm df = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\vec{i}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\vec{j}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\vec{i}\vec{j} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\vec{j}\vec{j}\right)\mathrm dr + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\vec{i}\vec{i} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\vec{j}\vec{i} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\vec{i}\vec{j} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\vec{j}\vec{j}\right)\mathrm dr^*.$$
Substituting $\vec{i}\vec{i} = \vec{j}\vec{j} = 1$ and $\vec{i}\vec{j} = -\vec{j}\vec{i} = i$ ($i$ is the imaginary unit):
$$\mathrm df = \frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) - i \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\right)\mathrm dr + \frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) + i \left(-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\right)\mathrm dr^*.$$
Thus:
$$\begin{cases} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \dfrac{1}{2}((\nabla \cdot f) - i[\nabla \times f]) \\ \vphantom0 \\ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r^*} = \dfrac{1}{2}((\nabla \cdot f^*) + i[\nabla \times f^*]) \end{cases},$$
where $f^* =  u\vec{i} - v\vec{j}$ and $\nabla = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\vec{i} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\vec{j}$.
Or, using the geometric product notation:
$$\begin{cases} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla f)^* \\ \vphantom0 \\ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r^*} = \dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla f^*) \end{cases}.$$
The formulas satisfy the algebra on $\mathbb{C}$:
$$\frac{\partial f^*}{\partial r} = {\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r^*}\right)}^*.$$
Is this correct? Does it make sense?
If yes, can we say $f(r)$ is differentiable when $\mathrm df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\mathrm dr$, which means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r^*} = 0$?
Also, are there any other indications in multivariable calculus that $\nabla$ can be redefined to include the $\frac{1}{2}$ factor?

Are you trying to derive the Wirtinger derivatives using 2D geometric algebra? In that case see section 4-7 (page 180) of Clifford Algebra to Geometric Calculus by Hestenes and Sobczyk. I think they have essentially what you wrote here, and also have the $\frac12$.
